# Why does the else statement not get executed if one of the bool parameters for if is null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code snippet here:

```
public void ReDrawParallelLines(string lineName, string viewType)
    {
        var referenceLineOne = GetLineParams(viewType + ReferenceEnum.One.ToString() + linename);
        var referenceLineTwo = GetLineParams(viewType + ReferenceEnum.Two.ToString() + linename);

        if (lineName == referenceLineOne.lineParams.lineName)
        {

           //Do certain action with referencelineone
        }
        else if (lineName == referenceLineTwo.lineParams.lineName)
        {
            //Do same action but with referencelinetwo

        }
    }
```

I noticed that if referenceLineOne is null but I have referenceLineTwo, the else statement never gets executed. I'm not sure why? Doesn't it work such that if the bool fails the if then continue to the else and it should pass for the else. It just skips the inside if statement and the else condition entirely because the referenceLineOne is null. Why and how can I correct this check?

Basically, I am passing a line name and I want to check to see if it's equal to one of two lines I get from the GetLineParams function.

Comment: hmm okay, the only reason referenceLineOne would be null is if the line is not yet drawn but I draw the referenceLineTwo first. I guess I need a better way to check if the lineName I pass is equal to a specific lineName so that I can run the proper condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `referenceLineOne` is null, you will get an exception, which is why it bypasses the else if and jumps somewhere else.

You should do null checking like this

```
if (referenceLineOne != null && lineName == referenceLineOne.lineParams.lineName)
{
   //Do certain action with referencelineone
}
```

or this if you use c#6

```
if (lineName == referenceLineOne?.lineParams.lineName)
{
   //Do certain action with referencelineone
}
```

Comment: Note that these two code snippets act very differently if `lineName` and `referenceLineOne` are both `null`.

Comment: @BenVoigt and by `lineName` I assume you mean the one one the left side of the `==`

Comment: @ohmusama: Yes, that's the one (it couldn't have been the other one)